# Adding time and dates together in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, time, momentjs

I need to add two 'times' together using meteor (and moment js if needed) to return a value in minutes. For example I have two dates:

Date 1: `Mon Dec 14 2015 23:40:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time)`
&
Date 2: `Mon Dec 14 2015 23:50:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time)`

I have tried doing the following:
Using moment to convert the two times to 'h:mm' format, running the asMinutes() function on them and then adding them together. This works fine until you start the time before 12PM and end it after.

I somehow need to add them together to return 10. This also has to take into account hours and days converting them all to minutes.

If anyone knows of a way around this that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to convert the times to milliseconds and then get the difference. Ie:

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
var difference = d2 - d1;
```

Or you can use Moment.js to do it as follow:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) // 86400000
```

Here are the relevant moment docs:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/